# А давайте в плюс к знаку "Фанатик" сделаем знак за год ежедневного посещения сайта?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, нытьё

Собственно, сабж. У меня не за горами уже год постоянного посещения и хочется за это значёк.

Стоит ли на это надеяться?

Comment: На МСО или МСЕ такое предложение было. Хозяева сказали, что стимулировать подобное маньячество не будут. :)

Comment: @Discord, ну вот( Я хочу мега-фанатика( Я даже тут вкладку уже >2 месяцев не закрываю только для значка(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, так вроде не работает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, так если браузер постоянно открытый и комп каждый день выключать/включать - то страница же с нуля грузится (в хроме по крайней мере), вот и получается, что открытая вкладка способствует получению значка )

Comment: @BOPOH, при 200+ вкладках точно нет гарантии, что грузится. Да и вообще, не факт.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну я же открываю (т.е. делаю эту вкладку активной), чтобы проверить ) а в хроме в последнее время даже уже ранее активные вкладки пытаются перезагрузиться (

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, ВОРОН всё верно говорит) Хром, комп вкл-вкл, вкладку тыкаю каждый раз и слежу как фанатик копится)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а я вот уже )))

Comment: Да я б ещё летом получил бы, но у нас на острове интернет отключился из-за сильного ветра(

Comment: Знак "Маньяк"? Было бы забавно :)

Comment: 100 дней уже достаточное маньячество =)

Comment: Мне мало) Я хочу быть официально главным маньяком)

Comment: Это принесет большому количеству пользователей страдания и невозможность уехать в отпуск в течение трех лет. Нельзя так. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну им ещё только в будущем принесёт сие страдание, а я вот прямо сейчас страдаю( [meta-tag:нытьё]

Comment: Меж тем у меня уже 480 дней насчитано подряд а значка всё нету(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб потому что надо подряд видимо 365........  у меня есть знак "годовалый"

Answer (score 12):

Предлагаю перенацелиться [на знак `Эпопея`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic). А потом – [на `Легенду`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary). Будет и регулярно, и мощно.

UPD. Другие знаки тоже могут стать наградой за длительность и регулярность усилий. Например:

[`Электорат`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) – полтора года плюсовать хотя бы по одному хорошему вопросу в день.

[`Главред`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) – три года корректировать по три сообщения в неделю.

Comment: К сожалению приходится работать и нет времени всё время отвечать чтобы эти знаки зарабатывать(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил ещё варианты.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky "Электорат" и "Главред" уже есть у Юрия :)

Comment: @alexolut Упс, проверял профиль Юрия на Мете вместо профиля на основном сайте. Спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 4):

Это не интересно. Требуется тупо не забывать заходить, причём кучу времени. Скучно и тупо. Причём можно даже абсолютно никакого вклада не вносить. Поэтому не стоит создавать такой знак, так как золотые значки (по идее) должны зарабатываться серьёзным трудом, а не за мартышкин труд, пусть даже долгий и напрасный. По моему мнению, значки должны поощрять по возможности именно вклад участника для других, а не какие-то бесполезные клики.

Comment: Ну, не знаю как у других, но вот у меня уже 659 дней подряд посещений и куча ответов и прочей активности, а вот никаких значков мне за это не дали( Я совсем не против дополнительных условий получения значка. Например год+ постоянных посещений и 30 000+ очков за этот период.

Comment: У меня сейчас на основном сайте: 
"На сайте 798 дней, из них 339 подряд"

Comment: @Qwertiy давайте меряться пи... "На сайте 586 дней, из них 458 подряд". :)