# Получить знак Фанатик несколько раз

Tags: поддержка, знаки, фанатик

Уже есть один [знак фанатик, выданный в 2016 году](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic?userid=213987).

Сейчас в профиле мне пишет, что я посещал сайт 104 дня подряд, но второго знака не видно.

[image: 104 days]

Я сначала думал, что он ровно на 100тый день присвоится, потом думал, что должно не менее 100 дней пройти (т.е. ждал на сто первый), но прошло уже несколько дней. Это баг?

Comment: Похоже, что нельзя: [Can you get more than one Enthusiast or Fanatic badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257967/5752652).

Comment: Вроде он однократный..

Comment: Где же ваш фанатик?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не баг, знак можно получить, действительно, только раз. И у него нет следующей версии типа "Заходил на сайт целый год каждый день". И это менять не хотят, т.к. сообщество тут у нас и там, в en-части, негативно к этой идее относится. [Пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2712/17609). А так да - обидно. У меня уже 978 дней подряд на основном сайте, но никто мне за это никакого значка не даст(

Comment: "никакого значка не даст" /// ромб же дали :)

Comment: @alexolut, но я хотел `убер-фанатик`(

Comment: То чувство когда ромб и даром не нужен, а золотой значок сверх-фанатика мечта.)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, вот да)